# How to typeset UTF-8 characters without affecting ASCII characters?

Tags: unicode

### The context

I'm working on a homework assignment for my Databases courses. I want to typeset the `⨝` character (JOIN operation from relational algebra) but at the same time I would like to have the following behavior when reading the PDF: when selecting and copying the character, it must be copied as it is.

I've done my research and so far I've gotten the following

```sh
lualatex main
```

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
$A ⨝ B$
\end{document}
```

When copying the `⨝` character in all the PDF viewers I've tried (`zathura`, `okular` and `firefox`), the character is copied as it is. I thought I had accomplished my goal. However, a new problem arises.

### The problem

The problem is that ASCII characters are not copied as ASCII characters in some PDF viewers. Okular is the only PDF viewer that copy `A` and `B` as ASCII characters (see below).

Using Firefox, the line is copied as

```sh
firefox --version
```

```
Mozilla Firefox 88.0.1
```

```
⨝
```

Using Okular, the line is copied as

```sh
okular --version
```

```
okular 21.04.0
```

```
A⨝B
```

Using Zathura, the line is copied as

```sh
zathura --version
```

```
zathura 0.4.7
girara 0.3.5 (runtime: 0.3.5)
(plugin) djvu (0.2.9) (/usr/lib/zathura/libdjvu.so)
(plugin) pdf-mupdf (0.3.6) (/usr/lib/zathura/libpdf-mupdf.so)
```

```
 ⨝
```

### The question

Is there any way to create a document that meet the following conditions

- Typeset the JOIN character such that when copying it in a PDF viewer, the `⨝` is inserted into the clipboard.
- Typeset the ASCII characters such that when copying them in a PDF viewer, ASCII characters are inserted into the clipboard.

In simpler words: Is there any package that would ensure that: When copying the selected characters from the generated PDF, the characters, that were used to typeset the ones from the PDF, are copied.

Here, the definition of a PDF viewer is any of the following: `okular`, `zathura`, built-in `firefox` PDF viewer. I'm just making clear since I know that there are many bad PDF viewers out there that would have different behaviors in the scenario presented here.

### Additional context

#### Behavior of `pdfgrep` and `pdftotext`

`pdfgrep` and `pdftotext` also interpret the ASCII characters of the PDF as non-ASCII characters.

```sh
pdfgrep '' main.pdf
```

```
⨝





      1
```

```sh
pdftotext main.pdf
cat main.txt
```

```
⨝

1
```

#### Trying every font in my TeXLive distribution

I thought that this problem was caused because of the specified font in `\setmathfont`. For this reason, I created the following script which generates a PDF for each OTF font in the default TeXLive installation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{...}

\begin{document}
foo $A ⨝ B$ bar
\end{document}
```

```sh
found="$(locate "/usr/local/*.otf")"
total="$(echo "$found" | wc -l)"
counter=1

for file in $found
do
  echo "Trying $file ($counter/$total)"
  echo "Trying $file ($counter/$total)" >> lualatex.log
  font=$(basename "$file")
  sed -i "s/\.\.\./$font/g" main.tex
  lualatex -interaction nonstopmode main 2>&1 >> lualatex.log
  exit_code=$?
  sed -i "s/$font/\.\.\./g" main.tex
  rm -f main.aux

  if [ "$exit_code" = 0 ]
  then
    mv main.pdf "$font.pdf"
    pdftotext "$font.pdf"
  fi
  counter=$((counter + 1))
done
```

The script took more than 30 minutes to finish and this is what I found. Of the 1702 `*.otf` fonts, the following fonts are the only ones that can typeset the `⨝` character.

```sh
grep -l -R --include="*.txt" '⨝' $my__experiments | sort
```

```
/home/beep1560/e/Asana-Math.otf.txt
/home/beep1560/e/Erewhon-Math.otf.txt
/home/beep1560/e/GFSNeohellenicMath.otf.txt
/home/beep1560/e/KpMath-Bold.otf.txt
/home/beep1560/e/KpMath-Light.otf.txt
/home/beep1560/e/KpMath-Regular.otf.txt
/home/beep1560/e/KpMath-Sans.otf.txt
/home/beep1560/e/KpMath-Semibold.otf.txt
/home/beep1560/e/NewCMMath-Book.otf.txt
/home/beep1560/e/NewCMMath-Regular.otf.txt
/home/beep1560/e/STIX2Math.otf.txt
/home/beep1560/e/STIX-Regular.otf.txt
/home/beep1560/e/XITSMath-Regular.otf.txt
```

Apparently, there is no font that typeset ASCII characters as ASCI characters because the following search yields no result

```sh
grep -l -R --include="*.txt" 'A.*⨝' $my__experiments | wc -l
```

```
0
```

So, I think that this is enough to think that this can be solved by using another font.

Comment: I think the issue here is that what looks like ASCII characters are in fact not. When you typeset with lualatex, your typical ‘A’ in a formula is rendered as , which is in fact the character U+1D434 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC CAPITAL A. Clearly, this is intentionally so. Whether there is a way to get what you want, I do not know. Here, more knowledgeable folks must pitch in.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen thanks for answering. I've already found a solution (see the first answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you are searching by specifying the following option: `math-style`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
$A ⨝ B$ \\
\end{document}
```

I tested this solution in the same versions of the software that you mentioned (because we are the same person).

I knew this because I searched `ASCII` in the `unicode-math` official documentation.  Next time, make sure that you look at the official documentation first (in this scenario, `$ texdoc unicode-math`) and search for keywords (in this scenario, `ASCII`).